# Blind source seperation on space data

Tags: pca, independent-component-analysis

in a uni project we gathered spectrum data from the ISS (time x frequency).
The challenge is now to analyse this data and especially try to seperate the signals.
As far as I understood it the common methods like ICA or PCA assume a stationary mapping from the source to the sensor.
However, the ISS is moving relative to the ground stations and satellites it records. 
My first thought was to have some kind adaptive mapping matrix A that is dependent on time, but I have no idea how to realize this.
Does anyone have an idea on what existing algorithms or methods might work?
The name of the method would be enough then I could dig deeper into it and try to teach it myself.